# Laravel eloquent filter on hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel

I am trying to filter on the field which has many relationships.

This is how my query looks:

```
Order::with(['fullOrderItems' => function($query) use ($branch) {
                $query
                    ->where('branch', $branch->key);
            }])
            ->orderBy('dateCreated')
            ->toSql();
```

The query looks like this once outputted:

```
select * from `Order` where `stage` <> ? order by `dateCreated` asc
```

And it seems like the query doesn't even consider the nested query for filtering the branch.

My relationship in `Order` class is defined like this:

```
/*
*
* @return HasMany|null
*/
public function fullOrderItemss() : ?HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItems::class, 'order', 'key');
}
```

Do you see what am I doing wrong here? How can I get the full query (including nested condition)?

Comment: with() is for eager loading your data, it only affects the additional data e.g. items but does not affect order. If you want your condition to affect order, use whereHas() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the Entity order with a relation you need to use `whereHas`

```
Order::whereHas('fullOrderItems', function($query) use ($branch) {
                $query
                    ->where('branch', $branch->key);
            })
            ->with(['fullOrderItems' => function($query) use ($branch) {
                $query
                    ->where('branch', $branch->key);
            }])
            ->orderBy('dateCreated')
            ->get();
```

You can for example get the order filtered by branch id but get all the `fullOrderItems` (ingore the branch id) of those `fullOrderItems` like this

```
Order::whereHas('fullOrderItems', function($query) use ($branch) {
                $query
                    ->where('branch', $branch->key);
            })
            ->with('fullOrderItems')
            ->orderBy('dateCreated')
            ->get();
```

This last example will make it simpler to understand the difference between the two filters.

For why the `with` condition doesnt show on the query:

it is used on a second unique query that fetchs the relation using the ids of orders retrieved in the first query. that way you get the orders, each with their respective fullOrderItems with only two queries.

Comment: Thanks! This worked when I repaired it a bit for whereHas. Please update your answer, so I can mark it as a solution

```whereHas('fullOrderItems', function($query) use ($branch) {
                $query
                    ->where('branch', $branch->key);
            })
```

Comment: @Boban you're right, forgot that whereHas doest support multiple relation in one method as an array.